# Limitar el número de elementos de un ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Hola buena mi pregunta sería como puedo limitar el número de elementos que puede contener un ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Cancion> aux = new ArrayList<Cancion>(3);
```

¿Esto estaría bien? Ya que cuando hago un .size(),  me sale "0" y no 3 como quiero yo.

Comment: La idea del `ArrayList` es contener un número **dinámico** de elementos, internamente utiliza un arreglo simple. El `3` que le estás pasando es el tamaño inicial de ese arreglo y cuando llamas a `size()` obtienes el número de elementos ocupados en el arreglo (que es 0), `0` sería el **tamaño**, `3` sería la capacidad. Te recomiendo leer la documentación de ArrayList y arreglos dinámicos.

Comment: `.size()` retorna la cantidad de elementos que hay _actualmente_ en la lista. Conviene que repases la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) :)

Comment: Para que `size()` te retorne 3 tienes que inicializar esos 3 valores, en dependencia de para que lo quieres utilizar (`0`, `null`), lo que estás seteando ahí es la capacidad del arreglo.

Comment: muchas gracias! , no estaba comprendiendo bien los ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Te sale **0** porque aún no has insertado nada, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
if(cont < 3)
{
   //Inserto en mi lista
   cont++;
}
```

Cuando aprietas el botón insertar primero se preguntaría si **cont** es menor a **3**, de serlo se inserta, de no serlo quiere decir que ya la lista tiene **3** elementos y que no se pueden insertar más.

**cont** sería una **variable global** de tipo **int** inicializada en **0**:

```
int cont = 0;
```

Otra forma es usando arreglos:

```
Cancion[] nombre = new Cancion[2];
```

Aquí se crea un arreglo de **3** elementos(en **Java** la primera posición es la **0**, por lo que la tercera sería el índice **2** del arreglo).